# Web Services SABRE matrix calendar

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sabre

I'm doing a .net c # application that returns me in matrix form for the day alternatives for a round trip for an origin and destination.

I want to know which webservices to use.

I also download the SabreDevStudioWidgetLibrary from the github page that is to be able to design the AlternateDatesMatrixLeadPriceCalendar, but I do not know how to make it work.

https://blog.developer.sabre.com/blog/2016/12/05/5-data-driven-widgets-pioneering-insight-onto-decision-support-bar/

thank you very much

regards

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for?

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/bfm_ad

Comment: If you have access rights to use Bargain Finder Max webservices, you just have to add some extra elements to your BFM request. <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
            <RequestType Name="AD1" />
            <CompressResponse Value="true" />
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
    </TPA_Extensions>

the "AD1" parameter means that you want +-1 day responses from your search date. You can increase day range with changing this parameter (for ex: you have to send "AD3" parameter in your request to get +-3 days response).